# Wordpress Category Page 2 go to 404

Tags: wordpress

i am making a website with custom taxonomy, and I have two problems:

1. The standard function of pagination I use is from [WP Beginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/), when I call her isn't working, the pagination is made with this code:

```
<div class="categoria__posts left-align">
  <?php previous_posts_link( '<span class="categoria__seta categoria__seta--esq">Projetos recentes</span>' ); ?>
</div>
<div class="categoria__posts right-align">
  <?php next_posts_link( '<span class="categoria__seta categoria__seta--dir">Projetos antigos</span>', $query->max_num_pages );?>
</div>
```

2. When I click in the previous_posts_link I go to a 404 page.

This is the codes I have:
WP Query

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

$queryName = get_queried_object()->name; //After a few searchs, some people say to put this, but that don't help me
$querySlug = get_queried_object()->slug;
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'projetos',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'cat' => $queryName, //After a few searchs, some people say to put this, but that don't help 
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms' => $querySlug,
    ),
  ),
);  
$query = new WP_Query($args); 
$count = 1; //It's here just for make the posts like the layout
if($query->have_posts()):
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 

POSTS
```

I search a lot how to solve this, but I can't found anything that work for me, any help will be amazing. I can send more of the code, but it's a little dirt for me see somethings more clear

Comment: Did you re-save your permalinks after registering your new custom taxonomy? If not, then go to Settings > Permalinks and click on Save to rebuild your permalinks structure.

Comment: I re-save the permalinks, every solution I found I test after re-save the permalinks, and without cache